What is the distribution of a windowed-sum binomial process?
Let's say I am flipping a fair coin.
If I do m independent trials of n flips, I expect the total flips of each trial to be distributed binomial(n,0.5), as I perform n*m flips in my experiment.  Basic Stats 101 stuff, there.
However, what happens if I do m+n-1 flips instead, and take m windowed sums of size n from the series, with m>0?  My gut tells me the totals will be distributed as some sort of right-truncated Poisson(0.5*n) for large enough m, because I'm modelling clusters of successes within discrete time windows.  However, that doesn't make sense because setting m=1 won't give the same distribution as binomial, and it should.
What is the rolling sum distributed as?

Each sum will still be distributed $\textrm{Binomial}(n,\frac12)$ but they will not be mutually independent (e.g. adjacent sums will be highly correlated because of the $n-1$ overlap of flips).

Do you know if there is a distribution for the joint, then?  How correlated is the overlap, based on window size?

If the overlap of two sets of $n$ flips is $k$ flips then the covariance between their sums $\big($each $\textrm{Binomial}(n,p)$ with $p=\frac12$ here$\big)$ is $kp(1-p)$ and the correlation is $\frac{k}{n}$.

That intuitively makes sense, since the variance of $k$ flips is $kp(1-p)$ though I would want to know a bit better where it comes from.  Do you have any idea what the distribution is for the number of flips before a set of overlapping flips at an extreme (say, 15 out of 20 flips heads) to return to the mean?  Some sort of negative binomial?

I'm slightly confused by the problem set up (I keep thinking I understand it and then losing it again). Suppose (for example) $m=2$ and $n=10$. Do you mean "flip a total of 11 times; take the average of the first 10 ($x_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{10} k_i/10$) and the last 10 ($x_2=\sum_{i=2}^{11} k_i/10$) ?
In that case, the sums (not the averages) will still have marginal $\textrm{Binomial}(p,10)$ distributions (assuming all the flips are still independent and have the same $p$) — we're still adding $n$ iid Bernoulli deviates, which gives us a binomial. The averages will be a "Binomial divided by $n$" distribution (i.e. $n \bar x \sim \textrm{Binomial}(...)$).  I don't know if the joint distribution of the sums has a name or not ...

I think I fixed all the "averages" in my question.  They all should have said "sum," but the two are interchangeable in my head.
It strikes me as odd, that the fact that the windowed sums aren't independent doesn't affect the variance of the distribution?  In your example, if I have (say) 6 heads, in the next I can only have 5, 6, or 7.  That makes it seem like the distribution should somehow depend on the trial numbers, or follow a Poisson, or something?
